# Let svg paths "intersect"

Tags: svg

sorry, but i don't know how to formulate this question ;)

I have a svg animation of an atom. (Not from me, just as an example)

http://codepen.io/davidsneighbour/pen/raPBRO

The three ellipsae (?) defined by path.class='atom-1' to 'atom-3' are at the moment on top of each other.

```
<path class="atom-1" fill="none" stroke="#555" stroke-width="8" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M231.7,200c0,17.4-1.7,88-31.7,88s-31.7-70.6-31.7-88s1.7-88,31.7-88S231.7,182.6,231.7,200z"/>
```

I would like to create an effect of 3-d-intersection so that each ellipsis is going at least once behind one of the other ellipsae, well, as if they are intertwined in 3d.

is this possible? how do I define some kind of z-index for parts of svg paths?

Comment: http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/knots.html

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for http://cs.sru.edu/~ddailey/canterbury/knot2.svg